# Fill an image inside a circle d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

In this topic , I tried to put a photo inside a circle in transition, so I have this image  fanta.jpg [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skwGx.jpg)

I want to put the image inside a circle with d3.js , that's my code :

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  #cv{
    width: 100%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <defs>
        <pattern id="image" x="-32" y="-32" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="64" width="64">
            <image  xlink:href="fanta.jpg"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
   <svg id="cv">
   </svg>
     <script>
           d3.select("#cv")
             .attr("height",300)
             .append("circle")
             .attr("r", 100)
             .attr('cx', 40)
             .attr('cy', 250)
             .attr('fill','url(#image)')
             .transition()
             .duration(4000)
            .attr('cx', 920)
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code begin with a svg that I created inside the html code ,I selected  properly the id of the svg , within css i gave a width 100% to the svg , then I added a height of 300 , finally I appended a circle to the svg where i tried to fill inside a photo fanta.jpg , that I put in transition , how can I fill the photo ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but maybe the following code snippet will help you out.

Keep in mind that `pattern` does exactly what it says, it creates a pattern. So when you fill your circle with the pattern, and then move the circle, it's as if the circle is revealing the tiled pattern of images below. Hopefully that makes more sense once you run my snippet.

```js
d3.select("#cv")
 .attr("height",300)
 .attr("width", 300)
 .style("border", "1px solid red")
 .append("circle")
 .attr("r", 100)
 .attr("cx", 100)
 .attr("cy", 100)
 .attr("stroke", "black")
 .style("fill", "#000")
 .style("fill", "url(#image)")
 .transition()
 .duration(4000)
 .attr("cx", 300)
```

```css
#cv{
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg id="cv">
<defs>
 <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="200" width="200">
      <image x="0" y="0" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/skwGx.jpg" width="200" height="200"></image>
    </pattern>
</defs>
</svg>
```